# Implementing insert and delete function on priority queue without array?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue, heap, priority-queue

I need to implement a priority queue without using array. 
I was trying to make it using a binary heap (Min heap), but I'm getting trouble when inserting a new element. Using array I just need to append the new element at the end of array and headpfy it, but without array I have to take care where I will insert it, because the binary tree can get very unbalanced.

I would like to know a solution for this binary heap without array or other data structure to use as min heap.

I will need to implement functions to insert and delete (can be the min element or other in the middle of the heap).

Same question, but not answered : [MinMax Heap implementation without an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698338/minmax-heap-implementation-without-an-array)

Thanks

Comment: You can implement a heap as a tree. This might be helpful, it gives a pretty good description of how you would implement a leftist heap tree structure.
https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/aads/Projects/3/
Note that this is from a university course, so it may change in the future.

Comment: Perhaps you could use an [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)  or a linked list ?

Comment: Using linked list to implement a heap is slow. Because to insert an element is O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common data structures used for this task are a Fibonacci heap, or a binomial heap:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap